# Is it thread-safe to use a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with a FlatFileItemReader and AsyncItemProcessor + Writer?

Tags: multithreading, csv, spring-batch

My job reads from a csv file (containing max about 65,000 rows), processes the data, and writes to a database. The following is my config --

```
    @Bean
    public Job csvFileLoadJob() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("csvFileLoadJob")
                .preventRestart()
                .start(csvFileLoadStep())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step csvFileLoadStep() throws Exception {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("csvFileLoadStep")
                .transactionManager(myTransactionManager)
                .<Map<String, String>, MyPojo>chunk(1000)
                .reader(csvFileReader(null))
                .processor(asyncCsvFileProcessor())
                .writer(asyncTableWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipPolicy(fileSkipHandler())
                .throttleLimit(5)
                .taskExecutor(csvFileLoadThreadPoolExecutor)
                .build();
    }
```

The reader reads each row into a map (by means of a custom `FieldSetMapper`). The writer calls a JpaRepository to write the converted entity (`MyPojo`) to a database.

Is the configuration thread-safe?

In the Spring Metadata tables, I can see that the read counts match the line count of the file. However, the target table counts -- **the records correctly inserted into the target table + exceptions logged into a separate table** -- far exceed the line count.

What can be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: Is there any reason why using both a multi-threaded step and an async processor/writer at the same time? Have you tried to use a single approach at  a time?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I'm trying to speed up the process. Despite my chunk size being set to 1000, the writer is always getting one record at a time. I was able to resolve the duplicate issue (answered below), but the latency issue remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out -- submitting an answer in case anyone else encounters the same issue.
It turns out that `faultTolerant()` was behind the duplicate exception logs. In the event of a failure, the chunk is rolled back and retried to isolate the bad record.

I was logging custom exceptions in the `fileSkipHandler()`, so the rollback + retry would result in a duplicate exception log. I was able to resolve this by implementing `@OnSkipInProcess`/`@OnSkipInWrite` methods to take care of the exception logging.

Used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558738/spring-batch-using-spring-boot-never-retry-on-write-error) thread for reference